# Identify the fallacy: X has red hair. Females have red hair. Therefore, X is female

Tags: fallacies

> Person A has trait X, therefore person A is group Y.
>
> Therefore, anyone with trait X is group Y.

What I'm trying to show is that Person A has red hair. Females have red hair. Therefore, person A is female. This is obviously not true, hence what is the fallacy of this called?

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [Aristotelian Syllogism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/), a "typical" case of fallacy is the [Fallacy of the undistributed middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_undistributed_middle).

The argument :

> All **z** is **B**
>
> All **y** is **B**
>
> > Therefore, all **y** is **z**

is not *valid*.

In your case you have an *individual* term in place of a *general* one, but the fallacy is basically the same; the argument :

> All **Chinese** are **men**
>
> **Socrates** is a **man**
>
> > Therefore, **Socrates** is a **Chinese**

is not *valid*.

Comment: But this is not the syllogism in play.  He is taking "All A are X", and "*Some* Y are X", and getting "All A are Y".  Which is even less valid.

Answer (score -2):

What you have is the following:

> **A** is **B**, Some **C** are **B**. Therefore, All **A** are **C**.

We cannot use *'All **C** are **B**'* because *'All females have red hair'* is not true. Also, it does not yield a contradiction. Structurally there is nothing wrong with: '**A** is **B**, All **C** is **B**. Therefore, All **A** are **C**'.

If *'**A** is **B**'*, it means they have a property in common, in this case **B** [the property of being redheaded]. We can treat them as equal, A = B.

> Some **C** are **B** = Some **C** are **A**

Thus, we can rewrite it as:

> Some **C** are **A**. Therefore, All **A** are **C**.

We have now found the contradiction, namely:

> 'All' ≠ 'Some'

Structurally,

> **A** is **B**, Some **C** are **B**. Therefore, All **A** are **C**.

is not valid. We cannot use this structure to deduce a conclusion.

**Edit:**

The fallacy is called **the undistributed middle**. In this case the problem is:

> All **Z** is **B**, Some **Y** is **Z**  Therefore, all **Y** is **B**

If we add the Z and Y to

> All **A** is **B** Some **C** is **B** Therefore, All **A** is **C**

we get:

> All **A** is **B [Z]** Some **C [Y]** is **B [Z]** Therefore, All **A** is **C [Y]**

We rearrange and compare:

> All **Z** is **B**, Some **Y** is **Z**  Therefore, all **Y** is **B**

with

> All **B [Z]** is  **A**,  Some **C [Y]** is **B [Z]** Therefore, All **C [Y]** is **A**

and conclude that the problem is *related* to the fallacy of **the undistributed middle**.

Comment: A is B, where B is an adjective, is nothing like A = B, where A and B are both nouns.  "X is red-haired" does not mean that X is just like all the red-haired or that any other the red-haired person necessarily has anything beyond that in common with X.

Comment: @jobermark Is Socrates like all mortal men? Does all mortal men like the same food? Does all mortal men love the same woman?

Comment: Exactly, having a property in common is not being the same.  So "We can treat them as equal, A = B" is misleading.  Also "Structurally there is nothing wrong with: 'A is B, All C is B. Therefore, All A are C'." makes no sense, unless "A is B" means A = B, but it only means that when A and B are both objects.  Structurally it is incorrect when B is a property, which it is.